# if statement in ruby, to determine input type

Tags: ruby, string, class, if-statement, integer

I'm trying to make a small hangman game in ruby. I am trying to validate the guess input using the following code:

```
puts "Enter a word: "
answer = gets.chomp
tries = 5
answer_array = answer.chars

until tries == 0
  hits = ""
  puts "enter your guess: "
  guess = gets[0]
  if guess.class != "String"
    puts "enter a letter!!"
  else
    puts "nice!!!"
  end
  tries -= 1
end
```

For some reason--whatever input I get for `guess`--the program throws "enter a letter!". Is there something wrong with the way I defined the if statement. I just want it to differentiate between a String and an Integer.

Comment: Try `if guess.class != String` or `not(guess.is_a? String)` or `guess.class.name != "String"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gets` always returns a String, so I don't think you want to validate its class. If you want to check that the input is a single letter, you can first check if the length of the input is 1:
`guess.length == 1`

Following that, you can check if it actually is a letter using regular expressions:
`(guess =~ /[A-Za-z]/) == 0`
That basically finds the position of the first letter in `guess`; as there should only be one letter at position 0, this condition will be true if guess is a letter.

So combined:

```
guess = gets.chomp # You want to remove the newline!
if (guess.length == 1) and (guess =~/[A-Za-z]/) == 0
  puts "Nice!"
  ...
else
  puts "Input a single letter!"
end
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `/[a-z]/i` for a case-insensitive regex.

Comment: Also: `guess.match(/\A[A-Za-z]+\z/)` tests if the line contains *one or more* characters, and in the latest ruby `match?` can do the test even more efficiently. The `(x =~ /.../) == 0` stuff is just plain bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

`guess.name` returns a constant which is `String`. You need to mind that `String` is different from `"String"`. When you enclose it in single quotes it becomes a string but not a constant.

So, change your if clause to

```
    if guess.class != String
       puts "enter a letter!!"
    else
       puts "nice!!!"
    end
```

or, use `.is_a?` method.

```
    if guess.is_a?(String)
       puts "enter a letter!!"
    else
       puts "nice!!!"
    end
```

Comment: Erm... It's probably also worth noting that this code is pointless, because `guess` will **ALWAYS** be a `String`! What we really want to do, surely, is something like: `guess = gets.chomp; if guess.length != 1 ....`

Comment: True. That makes sense too.

Comment: Or maybe even `if guess !~ /\A[a-zA-Z]\z/ ...`